# Trouble installing wxWIDGETS w/CodeLite

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I am trying to install wxWIDGETS w/CodeLite by following their instructions and it does not work. I am stuck on a step. Can you please help me? In case you're wondering, wxWIDGETS is a gui library for C++:

> Hello, I am trying to reinstall wxWIDGETS from the ground up. Here's
>   what I've done so far in one of the easiest explanations yet:
>
> I went on here for installation help with MINGW (the compiler):
>   https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installing_M ... er_Windows
>
> I went on here for installation help on compiling wxWIDGETS with MinGW
>   (to install it, am I right?): https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wx
>   ... tall_MinGW
>
> I've also done this: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Adding_an_En ...
>   er_Windows
>
> I've downloaded MinGW from here:
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/f ... e/download & then I've
>   reinstalled it.
>
> So, here's what I've done so far:
>
> Uninstalled/removed wxWIDGETS & MinGW (the compiler, I've
>   uninstalled/removed all of my compilers) → Reinstalled/re-added MinGW
>   and wxWIDGETS (https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/, I took the
>   Windows Installer under Source) → Followed these steps:
>   https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installing_M ... er_Windows → Followed
>   these steps: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Adding_an_En ... er_Windows →
>   Followed these steps: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wx ...
>   with_MinGW → Now I'm at the "Build the library" step and I'm
>   specifically on "Clean up the source:" and I am stuck on this step
>   w/an error that says "gcc_mswundll/wxjpeg_jctrans.o.d:1: *** missing
>   separator. Stop." how can I fix this? Can you please assist me?

Please help.

**Update 11/3/2015:**

This is the full-log of what I've done. I've deleted/removed and reinstalled CodeLite, wxWIDGETS, and even my minGW compiler & followed instructions as advised @ https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW

Now here is the full log as requested:

```
C:\Windows\system32>CD C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw

C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUI
LD=release clean
if exist gcc_mswudll\*.o del gcc_mswudll\*.o
if exist gcc_mswudll\*.d del gcc_mswudll\*.d
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxregexu.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxregexu.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxzlib.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxzlib.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxpng.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxpng.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxjpeg.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxjpeg.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxtiff.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxtiff.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxexpat.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxexpat.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxscintilla.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxscintilla
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30
u_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase30u_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase
30u_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase30u_net_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wx
base30u_net_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u_net.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u
_net.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u_net.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u
_net.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_core_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wx
msw30u_core_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_core.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_
core.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_core.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_
core.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_adv_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxm
sw30u_adv_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_adv.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_a
dv.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_adv.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_a
dv.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_media_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\w
xmsw30u_media_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_media.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u
_media.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_media.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u
_media.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_html_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wx
msw30u_html_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_html.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_
html.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_html.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_
html.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_webview_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll
\wxmsw30u_webview_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_webview.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw3
0u_webview.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_webview.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw3
0u_webview.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_qa_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxms
w30u_qa_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_qa.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_qa
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_qa.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_qa
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase30u_xml_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wx
base30u_xml_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u_xml.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u
_xml.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u_xml.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase30u
_xml.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_xrc_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxm
sw30u_xrc_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_xrc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_x
rc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_xrc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_x
rc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_aui_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxm
sw30u_aui_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_aui.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_a
ui.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_aui.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_a
ui.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_ribbon_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\
wxmsw30u_ribbon_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_ribbon.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30
u_ribbon.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_ribbon.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30
u_ribbon.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_propgrid_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dl
l\wxmsw30u_propgrid_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_propgrid.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw
30u_propgrid.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_propgrid.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw
30u_propgrid.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_richtext_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dl
l\wxmsw30u_richtext_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_richtext.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw
30u_richtext.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_richtext.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw
30u_richtext.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_stc_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxm
sw30u_stc_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_stc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_s
tc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_stc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_s
tc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw30u_gl_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxms
w30u_gl_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_gl.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_gl
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_gl.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw30u_gl
.a
mingw32-make -C ..\..\samples -f makefile.gcc LINK_DLL_FLAGS="-shared" LINK_MODU
LE_FLAGS="-shared" CC="gcc" CXX="g++" CFLAGS="" CXXFLAGS="" CPPFLAGS="" LDFLAGS=
"" CPP="gcc -E" SHARED="1" TOOLKIT_VERSION="" WXUNIV="0" UNICODE="1" MSLU="0" BU
ILD="release" DEBUG_INFO="default" DEBUG_FLAG="1" MONOLITHIC="0" USE_GUI="1" USE
_HTML="1" USE_WEBVIEW="1" USE_MEDIA="1" USE_XRC="1" USE_AUI="1" USE_RIBBON="1" U
SE_PROPGRID="1" USE_RICHTEXT="1" USE_STC="1" USE_OPENGL="1" USE_QA="0" USE_EXCEP
TIONS="1" USE_RTTI="1" USE_THREADS="1" USE_CAIRO="0" OFFICIAL_BUILD="0" VENDOR="
custom" WX_FLAVOUR="" WX_LIB_FLAVOUR="" CFG="" CPPUNIT_CFLAGS="" CPPUNIT_LIBS=""
 RUNTIME_LIBS="dynamic" GCC_VERSION="3" WINDRES="windres --use-temp-file" clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2/samples'
if exist .\*.o del .\*.o
if exist .\*.d del .\*.d
mingw32-make -C access -f makefile.gcc LINK_DLL_FLAGS="-shared" LINK_MODULE_FLAG
S="-shared" CC="gcc" CXX="g++" CFLAGS="" CXXFLAGS="" CPPFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" CPP=
"gcc -E" SHARED="1" TOOLKIT_VERSION="" WXUNIV="0" UNICODE="1" MSLU="0" BUILD="re
lease" DEBUG_INFO="default" DEBUG_FLAG="1" MONOLITHIC="0" USE_GUI="1" USE_HTML="
1" USE_WEBVIEW="1" USE_MEDIA="1" USE_XRC="1" USE_AUI="1" USE_RIBBON="1" USE_PROP
GRID="1" USE_RICHTEXT="1" USE_STC="1" USE_OPENGL="1" USE_QA="0" USE_EXCEPTIONS="
1" USE_RTTI="1" USE_THREADS="1" USE_CAIRO="0" OFFICIAL_BUILD="0" VENDOR="custom"
 WX_FLAVOUR="" WX_LIB_FLAVOUR="" CFG="" CPPUNIT_CFLAGS="" CPPUNIT_LIBS="" RUNTIM
E_LIBS="dynamic" GCC_VERSION="3" WINDRES="windres --use-temp-file" clean
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2/samples/access'
makefile.gcc:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2/samples/access'
makefile.gcc:44: recipe for target 'clean' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2/samples'
makefile.gcc:5096: recipe for target 'clean' failed
mingw32-make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've tried something different before as you shouldn't have any `.d` files in the first place if this were your first attempt to build. So to begin with you should return to the clean state: either delete your existing directory entirely and unpack the archive again or, if you're using git, do `git clean -dfx` (**warning**: this will delete all files not under version control).

After this running `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc` (with any extra options you need, such as `BUILD=release`) in `build\msw` subdirectory should work. If it doesn't, please update your question with the full command you used and its full output, and also mention which version of MinGW and wxWidgets exactly did you use.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question w/more details. I have the latest wxWIDGETS (3.0.2 version) & the latest minGW compiler (shouldn't be a problem right?) Please help me & take a look at my full log. BTW: I deleted MSYS directory as stated here: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW.

Comment: I don't know what happened with `samples/access/makefile.gcc`, it looks like it might be using DOS EOL format instead of the Unix one that make probably expects. However unless you really need to build the samples, you could ignore this problem for now and just build the library, why are you trying to clean anyhow if you hadn't built anything yet?